# Is wordnet a treebank?

Tags: wordnet, treebanks

Is wordnet an example of a treebank? If not, what are the differences? I'm not sure but may be a treebank contains parse trees but wordnet does not.
Thanks.

Comment: 'I'm not sure but may be a treebank contains parse trees but wordnet does not.' That's exactly right.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Treebanks are about **sentences** analysed with syntax trees (constituent and/or dependency parsing).

Wordnets are about semantic relation between **words** like hypernymy and hyponymy.

The two resource types have different objects as their contents and they are analysing different kinds of relations between those objects. Besides being linguistic resources for specific languages, they have almost nothing in common.